# Imprimir valores do request.form

Tags: html, asp

Tenho o seguinte código abaixo, e pertendo quando clicar no botão gravar executar as duas primeiras responses. Mas eles estão a imprimir campos vazios. O que está de errado no meu código?

CÓDIGO:

```
<%
    Dim year_, lista(), cList, x, vHol()
    year_=year(date())

    response.write request.form("lista(0,1)")
    response.write request.form("valor_1")

    call LoadUsers()
%>

<form action="layOff.asp?sid=<%=sid%>&opc=sav" method="POST" name="form" style="margin-top:0;">
    <table width="98%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
        <tr>
            <td class=Font9Bold><br><%=msg("90130", lng)%></td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="25" bgcolor="#efefef">
            <td colspan=3 style="border-color:'navy';border-style:solid;border-top-width:1px;border-bottom-width:1px;border-right-width:0px;border-left-width:0px;">
            &nbsp;<input class=Button type="submit" name="submit" value=" <%=msg("50001", lng)%> ">
            &nbsp;<input class=Button type="Button" name="Submit" value=" <%=msg("50002", lng)%> " OnClick="location.href='../mnt/manut.asp?sid=<%=sid%>'">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr height="30">
            <td><br/></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class=Font9Red colspan=2>
                <%=sMsg%>
            </td>
        </tr>
     </table>

    <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
      <tr height="25" bgcolor="#efefef" class=Font10Bold>
        <td width="50" style="border-color:'navy';border-style:solid;border-top-width:1px;border-bottom-width:1px;border-right-width:0px;border-left-width:0px;">
            <%=msg("90002", lng)%>
        </td>
        <td width="400" style="border-color:'navy';border-style:solid;border-top-width:1px;border-bottom-width:1px;border-right-width:0px;border-left-width:0px;">
            <%=msg("90033", lng)%>
        </td>
        <td align="center" width="60" style="border-color:'navy';border-style:solid;border-top-width:1px;border-bottom-width:1px;border-right-width:0px;border-left-width:0px;">
            <%=msg("90130", lng) & " " & year_%> 
        </td>
      </tr>
      <% FOR x=0 to cList-1%>
      <tr class='Font10'>
          <td><%=lista(x,1)%></td>
          <td><%=lista(x,2)%></td>
          <td align="center"><input class=NumberBox type="text" name="valor_<%=x%>" value="<%=ValueHol(lista(x,0))%>" size="3" maxlength="2"></td>
      </tr>
      <%NEXT%>
    </table>
    <br/><br/><br/><br/>
</form>

<%
    Function LoadUsers()
        Dim y, i

        sSQL="SELECT tbUsers.uid, tbUsers.user_, tbUsers.name "
        sSQL=sSQL & "FROM tbUsers "
        sSQL=sSQL & "WHERE user_<>'ADMIN' "
        sSQL=sSQL & " ORDER BY name"
        Set RS = MyConn.Execute(sSQL)

        cList=0
        while not rs.EOF
            cList=cList+1
            rs.MoveNext
        wend
        Set RS = MyConn.Execute(sSQL)

        redim lista(cList,2)

        i=0
        while not rs.EOF
            lista(i,0)=rs("uid")
            lista(i,1)=rs("user_")
            lista(i,2)=rs("name")
            i=i+1
            rs.MoveNext
        wend
    End Function

    Function ValueHol(uid)
        sSQL="SELECT days_year "
        sSQL=sSQL & "FROM tbLayOffTop "
        sSQL=sSQL & "WHERE uid='" & uid & "'"
        Set RS = MyConn.Execute(sSQL)

        if not rs.eof then
            ValueHol=rs("days_year")
        end if      
    End Function

    Sub save()
        For i=0 to cList-1
            sSQL="DELETE * FROM tbLayOff WHERE year_='" & year_ & "' AND month_='" & i & "' AND uid=" & lista(i,0)
            Set RS = MyConn.Execute(sSQL)

            sSQL="INSERT INTO tbLayOff (year_, uid, days_year"
            sSQL2="insert_by, insert_date) "
            sSQL3="VALUES ('" & year_ & "', '" & lista(i,0) & "', " &  document.all("valor_" + cstr(i)).value & "', "

            sSQL=sSQL & sSQL2 & sSQL3 & "'" & uid & "', " & "'" & date_now & "')"
            response.write sSQL
        Next    
    End Sub
%>
```

Comment: Você faz um POST para uma página também enviando um Querystring? Não tem algo de errado ai? Transfira a querystring `sid=<%=sid%>&opc=sav` para dois Hiddens dentro de seu form e tente novamente.

Answer (score 0):

seu formulário está configurado para "post" e alem disso o action contem informação "GET".

Para receber dados via POST no asp é utilizado `request.form("campo")`
Para receber dados via GET no asp é utilizado `request.QueryString("campo")`

Para receber ambos POST ou GET, digite somente `request("campo")`

```
response.write request("lista(0,1)")
response.write request("valor_1")
response.write request("sid")
response.write request("opc")
```